# How to post full name drawn from MySQL using only username as login, in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, variables, fetch

SOLVED: After rewriting the mysql and membership code several times, the last one worked when mysqlind (native driver) was enabled.

---

I have this login script that works perfectly, but I want it to post to my pages the full name of the user that is logged in.

I want it to fetch and post, firstname and lastname in a div on any given page using the username given to session at login.

Login script:

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once 'classes/membership.php';
$membership = new Membership();

// If the user clicks "Log Out".
if(isset($_GET['status']) && $_GET['status'] == 'loggedout') {
$membership->log_User_Out();
}

// Did the user enter a password/username and click submit?
if($_POST && !empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['pwd'])) {
$response = $membership->validate_User($_POST['username'], $_POST['pwd']);
}
?>
```

Checking credentials in membership.php:

```
<?php

require 'mysql.php';

class Membership {

function validate_user($un, $pwd) {
    $mysql = New Mysql();
    $ensure_credentials = $mysql->verify_Username_and_Pass($un, md5($pwd));

    list($ensureCredentials, $data) = $mysql->verify_Username_and_Pass($un, md5($pwd));

if($ensure_credentials) {
    $_SESSION['status'] = 'authorized';
    $_SESSION['fname'] = $data['fname'];
    $_SESSION['lname'] = $data['lname'];
    header("location: medlem.php");
} else return "Please enter correct username and password";
    print_r($row);
    exit;

} 

function log_User_Out() {
    if(isset($_SESSION['status'])) {
        unset($_SESSION['status']);

        if(isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])) 
            setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 1000);
            session_destroy();
    }
}

function confirm_Member() {
    session_start();
    if($_SESSION['status'] !='authorized') header("location: login.php");
}

}
```

Establishing connection to mysql in mysql.php:

```
<?php

require_once 'includes/constants.php';

class Mysql {
private $conn;

function __construct() {
    $this->conn = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or 
                  die('There was a problem connecting to the database.');
}

function verify_Username_and_Pass($un, $pwd) {

$query = "SELECT *
        FROM users
        WHERE username = ? AND password = ?
        LIMIT 1";

if($stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query)) {
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $un, $pwd);
    $stmt->execute();
    // UPDATE : I added correct usage of the stmt here.    
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    if($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
       $stmt->free_result();
       $stmt->close();                
        // returning an array the first item is the validation the second is the data. 
        return array(true, $row);
    }
}
// if there is no just return empty data, and false for validation.
return array(false, array());
}
```

And for the sake of re-usability I define constants in constants.php:

```
<?php

// Define constants here

define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USER', 'myusername');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'mypassword');
define('DB_NAME', 'membership');
```

How can I easily get it to retrieve firstname (fname) and lastname (lname) from MySQL database, when the session only knows the username of the logged in user.

As I stated above the row names for first and last name are fname and lname.

I want to display it as easy as possible with a floating CSS formated div id'ed topr, like so:

```
<?php 
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['status'])){
    echo "<div id='topr'>Welcome, " . $_SESSION['fname'] . "!</div>";
} ?>
```

I mainly focus on displaying the firstname first. By the time I get that right I will surely have it display lastname to.

Just want to learn more about this. As my web searches didn't come up with anything that I could manage to implement in my code without messing something up.

Comment: I guess you need to fetch name here `verify_Username_and_Pass` and then add it into `session` here `validate_user` along with your `status`

Comment: I am afraid you need to be more spesific than that since I am fairly new to PHP. But thanks for the comment, every helping hand is so much appriciated!

Comment: 1) Is the field `username` in your table `users` unique? 2) Your field `fname` and `lname` are both together with `username` in the same table `users` ?

Comment: (1 Yes (2 They are in the same table, correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your verify function as follow. I added related comments.

```
function verify_Username_and_Pass($un, $pwd) {

    $query = "SELECT *
            FROM users
            WHERE username = ? AND password = ?
            LIMIT 1";

    if($stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query)) {
        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $un, $pwd);
        $stmt->execute();
        // UPDATE : I added correct usage of the stmt here.    
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        if($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
           $stmt->free_result();
           $stmt->close();                
            // returning an array the first item is the validation the second is the data. 
            return array(true, $row);
        }
    }
    // if there is no just return empty data, and false for validation.
    return array(false, array());
}
```

So in your MemberShip class where you call verify_Username_and_Pass just get the array data in to variables. and use it send to session variables.
So you will be eligible to use session in where ever you wanted.

```
   list($ensureCredentials, $data) = $mysql->verify_Username_and_Pass($un, md5($pwd));
   if($ensure_credentials) {
        $_SESSION['status'] = 'authorized';
        $_SESSION['first_name'] = $data['first_name'];
        $_SESSION['last_name'] = $data['last_name'];
        header("location: medlem.php");
    } else return "Please enter correct username and password";
```

Comment: Good to hear that. So I just aware now you don't need to add isExist and the data key to array. Without the keys it is also OK.

Comment: I've implemented the code, and thanks alot for a wonderful explanation following it. Really appriciate your help! But still when I try to post these in my div using $data['first_name'] and $data['last_name'] it only shows "Welcome, " then the rest is blank. The code I am trying use inside my pages goes as follows: <?php session_start(); if(isset($_SESSION['status'])){ echo "<div id='topr'>Velkommen, " . $data['first_name'], $data['last_name'] . "!</div>"; } else { "<div id='topr'>Velkommen, du er ikke logget inn.</div>"; } ?>

Comment: The rows in my DB for first and lastname are called fname and lname. I've also tried using that but still does nothing. And I've tried to add $_SESSION['/*bla bla bla*/'] to specify the variables in the page files as well. Didn't make any difference.

Comment: OK firstly, you shouldn't use $data['first_name'] in the div section, even at the rest of your application. You have to use $_SESSION['first_name']. If you pay attention to `if($ensure_credentials)` part in my answer I assigned related indexes of $data to $_SESSION.  first_name, and last_name are just example use exactly yours. Actually I suggest you. just dump your $row `print_r($row); exit;` after `if($ensure_credentials)` and see the result and use exact keys.

Comment: Offcourse! I was on a strole in backwards land for a second there. Thanks alot! I'll go ahead and rewrite it right away and post the outcome after.

Comment: How do I see the results from the print_r? Sorry once again, total noob over here. Google only tells me what it does not how to actually read it. Still rewritten to post $_SESSION in all parts it does not give me the information I was hoping for. I must be the worst attempt on a coder you've ever seen..

Comment: You don't need to execuse StackOverflow is for the learning, but I highly suggest you read session related articles, I think it would make you understand more details and it would be a nicer way. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp will give you absolute basics, and I just checked there is also print_r usage in the examples. Please check them and try to understand exact problem and another tip is just echo it, or print_r it your variables step by step it is the best debugging in the context. So if those doesn't help just write back here. I will try my best.

Comment: and Please update your question with the new code it would make us figure out what is the potential problematic section.

Comment: Such a great person! Thanks alot, I will give w3schools a try. I've been there alot, but reading isn't my strongest value. Thanks again! I will update the code right away! :)

Comment: I understood the consept of print_r finally and executed in one off my pages and it came back with this result: Array ( [status] => authorized [fname] => [lname] => ). So it looks like its not picking anything up using those variables. I'll add, this was using print_r($_SESSION), so I know that lname and fname are in the session correctly. But since we are talking about $row as a variable. If fname and lname are two unique coloums in the same table. Does that change anything?

Comment: Cool it is a point, so it means when we assign $data to $_SESSION there may be a problem. $data looks like empty, your row in mysql may be  hold an empty fname lname. So could you please add print_r($data); right after if($ensure_credentials) statment and paste result here.

Comment: print_r($data) does not show anything. Also the user I am trying to login have filled out both fname and lname

Comment: Also if I add the print_r in any of the "require" files it does not print since it is only pass through. Does not actually print anything on my pages. Am I doing something wrong again?

Comment: It would seem that the error is in the if statement for $row maybe?

Comment: according to http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php docs stmt::fetch does returns just bool variable, so it is my fault I assigned fetch result to $row. It is not a correct way, stmt's bind params is not an idomatic way with the unspecified columns  so I updated my answer and added correct usage. Please check and try.

Comment: Aha, do I have to edit membership.php to so that $_SESSION['whatever'] equals $row['whatever']?

Comment: Comes back with: Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() in /home/sameige/public_html/classes/mysql.php on line 24

Comment: Interesting the docs says http://php.net/manual/tr/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php there is. Could you please update your question with the new code, you may miss some code around. No there is nothing to change for session lines.

Comment: I have updated the code exactly to what I am trying to run. Finally did some reading as you suggested, and found out that I need mysqlnd (native driver) in order to run get_result. How do I get about enabling this? EDIT: Did some research on my remote server settings and found that mysqlnd is installed and running on the current version I am running.

Comment: Did some extra researching and since I was running a statement query in mysqli I thought that I need the native driver for mysqli. Installed it, and now the code runs perfectly fine. I will now try to print_r the $row var and see if it did anything!

Comment: Thanks alot FZE! Everything is now finally running smoothly. You gave me the stuff needed for me to finally put those reading skills to good use, and figuring out the small errors. Thanks again man!

Comment: Your very welcome, I highly suggest you if you are insisting to scripting start to read PHP language reference manual http://php.net/manual/en/langref.php.

Answer (score 0):

One way might be to do this:

In `verify_Username_and_Pass()` instead of returning just boolean true, return the first and last name; on error/failure, return false.

That way the if-statement in `validate_user()` in `Membership` class can still work as-is. Then, all you need to do is save that info into your session via `$_SESSION['full_name'] = $ensure_credentials;`